# Создание функции

Tags: c

Вот как исправил все равно не работает

```
int main(void)
{
    char** words = NULL; // указатель на слова
    int num_words = 0; // кол во слов
    char* delim = " \t\n,.!?:";
    int size_file = 0; //размер файла
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_file = ftell(fp); //находим размер файла
    printf("%d\n", size_file);
    char* buffer = calloc(size_file + 1, sizeof(char)); //буфер

    if (buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка выделения памяти\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, 1, size_file, fp);

    printf("\nТекст файла\n\n");
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    char* istr = strtok(buffer, delim);   
   words = file_words(buffer, words, &num_words, delim);


    printf("Количество символов в файле :%d\n", size_file);
    printf("Количество слов в файле :%d\n\n", num_words);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
       // puts(words[i]);
    }
```

Вот как пытался реализовать функцию отдельно:

```
    char** file_words(char *f_istr, char **word, int *n_word, char *del) {
  while (f_istr) {
        word = realloc(word, (*n_word + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        word[*n_word++] = f_istr;
        f_istr = strtok(NULL, del);
    }
 return word;
}
```

Но с ней программа перестает работать(ошибок нет, просто перестает считывать слова

Comment: Что это "Хочу функцию из часть функций" значит ?

Comment: Немного задумался видимо пока писал)

Comment: Сможете подсказать что не так?

Comment: Ошибка вот тут -- `word[*n_word++] = f_istr;` (вы увеличиваете указатель при каждом выполнении этой строки, а не переменную, но которую он указывает). Нужно `word[(*n_word)++] = f_istr;`

Answer (score 1):

В функции был не полностью реализован алгоритм по работе с текстом.

```
char** file_words(char *buffer, char **word, int *n_word, char *del)
{
    char* f_istr = strtok(buffer, del);

    while (f_istr) {
        word = realloc(word, ((*n_word) + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        word[(*n_word)++] = f_istr;
        f_istr = strtok(NULL, del);
    }
    return word;
}
```

Эта функция заменяет данный участок кода:

```
    printf("\nТекст файла\n\n");
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    words = file_words(buffer, words, &num_words, delim);

    /*
    //char* istr = strtok(buffer, delim);
    //пытался перенести эту функцию
     while (istr) {
        words = realloc(words, (num_words + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        words[num_words++] = istr;
        istr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    */
```

Comment: Да, с многофайловыми программами работал, сделал как вы, все равно просто игнорирует эту функцию. Может я что то не то передаю?

Comment: Заголовочный файл не обязательно писать, а если и писать, то можно вместо #ifndef писать #pragma once. Вместо такого файла можно в файле, где вызывается функция объявить эту функцию с типами параметров и возвращаемым типом

Comment: Да, можно и так, но все таки ошибка не в этом. Он просто ничего не выполняет в этой функции. Если тоже самое делать  в мейне, то все работает

Comment: А вы в главном файле подключили вашу библиотеку с функцией ? И настроили линковку файлов ?

Comment: Да, никаких варнингов не было. Попытался сделать эту функцию просто выше мейна, точно такой же результат, могу кинуть repl, если хотите увидеть своими глазами

Comment: @ЯрославЗахаров, у вас ошибка в самой функции. Вы не полностью реализовали алгоритм разделения текста на массив строк (в 3ем параметре количество слов передаётся по ссылке).

Comment: То есть надо как то подправить 3 параметр в функции?

Comment: @ЯрославЗахаров, да я уже исправил, просто у вас в 3ем параметре количество слов, которое понадобится при их выводе, а вы его не возвращаете => вы не знаете, сколько у вас слов записано в памяти. Т.е. по итогу работы вашей программы переменная num_words так и оставалась бы равной '0'.